# Integral $\int_{S}\frac{dydz}{x}+\frac{dxdz}{y}+\frac{dxdy}{z}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

S is the sphere of outward oriented unit, integral:
$$\int_{S}\frac{dydz}{x}+\frac{dxdz}{y}+\frac{dxdy}{z}=?$$
I want to use the Gauss-Ostrogradsky formula, but the $\frac{1}{x}$ function is not continuous at $0$

Answer (score 1):

This integral can in fact be computed fairly easily directly. but perhaps it might be worthwhile to note that on any smooth oriented $2$-dimensional surface $\Sigma$ in $\Bbb{R}^3$ if $n$ denotes the outward unit normal, and $dA$ denoted the area element on $\Sigma$ then $n_1 \cdot dA = dy \wedge dz$ and $n_2 \cdot dA = dz \wedge dx$ and $n_3 \cdot dA = dx \wedge dy$.

For the case of a sphere, $S_R$, of radius $R$, we have $n_1 = \dfrac{x}{R}$, $n_2 = \dfrac{y}{R}$ and $n_3 = \dfrac{z}{R}$. So, plugging into the above formula, we find that on the sphere,
\begin{align}
dy \wedge dz = dz \wedge dx = dx \wedge dy = \dfrac{1}{R} dA
\end{align}
Therefore, the integral you seek is
\begin{align}
\int_{S_R} \dfrac{3}{R} \, dA = \dfrac{3}{R} (4\pi R^2) = 12 \pi R
\end{align}

---

it is also a good idea to use the definition of surface integrals to compute this directly (atleast for one of the terms). i.e parametrize the sphere using polar coordinates
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
x &= R \sin \theta \cos \phi \\
y &= R \sin \theta \sin \phi \\
z &= R \cos \theta
\end{cases}
\end{align}
($0 < \theta < \pi$ and $0 < \phi < 2 \pi$). and compute the respective matrix of partial derivatives, and its determinant, plug it into the definition of surface integral and see that you get the same answer.

Comment: I'm brave to use
$\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
x &= R \sin \theta \cos \phi \\
y &= R \sin \theta \sin \phi \\
z &= R \cos \theta
\end{cases}
\end{align}$But don't know dxdy, dydz dzdx = ???

Comment: $dx=x_RdR+x_{\phi}d \phi+x_{\theta}d \theta$ perhaps?